# How to get next/previous double records in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

hello everyone I ask for help to understand how to proceed with the sql code
I have a table set as in the photo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKKdb.png)

in the kiss_count cell do duplicates in the records, see photos.
how can I retrieve records for example from 6 onwards? I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't respect the list, skip kiss_count 6 and go directly to 2, the problem is that there are duplicates like 6 6 or 11, how can I proceed? I could lean on the id list to respect the calls in the right irdine, the code that yso is this:

```
WHERE kiss_count < '6'  ORDER BY kiss_count_total DESC LIMIT 5");
```

the question is can I order a list with duplicates?

I have also tried this

```
WHERE kiss_count < '6' AND ID < '8'  ORDER BY kiss_count_total DESC LIMIT 5");
```

BUT IT DOES NOT WORK

Comment: Is your question `how can I retrieve records from 6 and higher?` or `how can I order a list with duplicates?`

Comment: the question is ohow can I order a list with duplicates? -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to order the `kiss_count` field which has duplicates. To do this you need to use an extra field. Reading the title, you also want to be able to get the next 5 values.

You can use the `order by` on 2 columns, no need for the `where` clause:

```sql
select * from my_table order by kiss_count desc, id asc;
```

Because the query `select * from my_table order by kiss_count desc, id asc` always gives you the same sequence, you can grap results using `offset`.

So in your example, the second page should have an `offset` of 5, and a `row_count` of 5:

```sql
// page 2
select * from my_table order by kiss_count desc, id asc limit 5, 5;
// page 3
select * from my_table order by kiss_count desc, id asc limit 10, 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is skipping 6 because it searching for `kiss_count < 6`. 
You should check for `kiss_count <= 6`

```
WHERE kiss_count <= '6'  ORDER BY kiss_count_total DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Comment: if it has duplicates how can i start from that specific 6, should i have the id's support?

Comment: @ILFREEit If you want to get them ordered by id us can use `ORDER BY id`. Do you want to return also the duplicates ?